# How to insert comments in lightning aura components that are not shown in the generated HTML?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html, comments, internal-comments

The lightning aura component comment syntax common to HTML `<!-- comment -->` generates a comment also in the generated HTML.

There is a way to insert comments in the source code of the .cmp file of the lightning aura component that does not generate a corresponding comment in the generated HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an "official" way to do this but one quick way to accomplish this would be to wrap your comment in an aura:if tag:

`<aura:if isTrue="false">Insert comment here</aura:if>`

This is pretty hacky but you could easily create a component called "comment" that accomplishes the same thing and would look better like this:

`<c:comment>Insert comment here</c:comment>`

Comment: +1 just because it works... in theory. Practically, there is no way that it is advisable to insert nop code just to insert comments. :(

Answer (score -1):

Insert comments using

```
<!-- This is your comment -->
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_markup.htm

Comment: I think that you didn’t bother reading the question.